# Reference, about complete list & complete classification, about software design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, software-design

when i refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), it classify design pattern by using GoF patterns.
but then, there is [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design), which is not within GoF patterns.
also there is [J2EE Design Pattern](https://www.javatpoint.com/jee-or-j2ee-design-patterns), which could not be found in Wikipedia.
then there is [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which is another design pattern.

it looks like, there is no reference available,
that can describe, the complete list & complete classification, about design pattern.

or anyone know, the best reference about design patterns ? 
the one that contains complete list & complete classification.

Answer (score 0):

As [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) says:

> A software design pattern is a general, reusable solution to **a commonly occurring problem** within a given context in software design. It is not a finished design that can be transformed directly into source or machine code.

it can be concluded that it is not efficient to have one source which can describe all patterns because some challenge might occur and this reference will not have the design pattern to solve that task.